# Conflict between ntheorem and amsthm

Tags: packages, theorems, incompatibility, etoolbox, ntheorem

I am using `etoolbox` and `ntheorem` packages to have a custom numbering of theorems and equations. Everything works but these side errors occur:

- `\qedhere` command is unknown (EDIT: *following some suggestions I worked something out, so the `\qedhere` issue is somehow solved*)
- theorems title (the optional argument) is typeset in bold

As a MWE, the following code

```
\documentclass{book}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{etoolbox}  
\usepackage[amsmath,amsthm,framed,thmmarks]{ntheorem}  
%  
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}  
\setcounter{equation}{0}  
\newcounter{tempcounter}  
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]  
%  
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{thm}{\setcounter{tempcounter}{\arabic{equation}}}  
\AtBeginEnvironment{thm}  
{\setcounter{thm}{\thetempcounter}\subequations}  
\AtEndEnvironment{thm}{\endsubequations}  
%  
\begin{document}  
\chapter{This is a chapter}  
\begin{equation}\label{Eq:A}  
2+2=4  
\end{equation}  
\begin{thm}[First Theorem]\label{Thm:First}  
\begin{equation}\label{Eq:B}  
1+1=2  
\end{equation}  
\begin{proof}  
If equation \ref{Eq:A} was trivial, equation \ref{Eq:B} in Theorem \ref{Thm:First} is even more \qedhere \\  
trivial.  
\end{proof}  
\end{thm}  
\end{document}
```

results in this output:

[image: Output of the above MWE]

The `\qedhere` command is unknown and therefore ignored. I think that the problem is a conflict between the `amsthm` option in `ntheorem` package and the `amsthm` package. However, if I add `\usepackage{amsthm}` in the preamble I get errors like

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \theoremstyle already defined.
```

and many more.

I would like either to solve the two problems listed above, or to have an alternative code in order to have:

- theorems and equations following the same numbering, resetting at each chapter
- equations in theorem environments subnumbered as shown in the above MWE's output.

Any other suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: `\qedhere` is not among the "supported" features from `amsmath`.  the `ntheorem` documentation states that "some features of `amsthm` have been incorporated into option `[amsthm]`".  the operative word here is "some".  if you would like to have `\qedhere` supported, i suggest writing to the authors of `ntheorem`.

Comment: @barbara-beeton Thank you for the suggestion, I sent an email to the author. I am leaving the question open to other suggestions anyway.

Comment: since you wish to use `ntheorem`, not `amsthm` (except for some features), the suggestion to ask the authors of `ntheorem` to add `\qedhere` wasn't intended as a real answer.  however, [this tex file](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/author-info/documentation/howto/extra-qed.tex) (which *does* depend on `amsthm`) offers some suggestions intended to enable the setting of a qed-type symbol outside of `proof` environments that may give you some ideas of how to handle the problem temporarily with manual adjustments.

Comment: As I outlined in the last EDIT, thanks to these suggestions I worked something out for the `\qedhere` issue. Now the question shrinks to the _bold theorem title_ problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ntheorem` package covers the `\qedhere` in different ways. Here's an example on which you can elaborate. The "normal font attribution" is easily obtained by (re)defining the theorem style.

```
\documentclass{book}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}  
\usepackage{etoolbox}  
\usepackage[amsmath,framed,thmmarks]{ntheorem}  
%  
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\newcommand{\qedhere}{\ifmmode\qed\else\hfill\proofSymbol\fi}

\makeatletter
\renewtheoremstyle{plain}
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\ {\normalfont(##3)}\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{plain}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]

\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
\qedsymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}

\newcounter{tempcounter}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{thm}{\setcounter{tempcounter}{\arabic{equation}}}  
\AtBeginEnvironment{thm}  
{\setcounter{thm}{\thetempcounter}\subequations}  
\AtEndEnvironment{thm}{\endsubequations}  
%  
\begin{document}  
\chapter{This is a chapter}  
\begin{equation}\label{Eq:A}  
2+2=4  
\end{equation}  
\begin{thm}[First Theorem]\label{Thm:First}  
\begin{equation}\label{Eq:B}  
1+1=2  
\end{equation}  
\begin{proof}  
If equation \ref{Eq:A} was trivial, equation \ref{Eq:B} in Theorem \ref{Thm:First} is even more
trivial.
\[ 0+0=0 \qedhere\]
\end{proof}  
\end{thm}  

\begin{thm}[Second Theorem]\label{Thm:Second}  
\begin{equation}\label{Eq:C}  
1+1=2  
\end{equation}  
\begin{proof}  
If equation \ref{Eq:A} was trivial, equation \ref{Eq:C} in Theorem \ref{Thm:Second} is even more
trivial.
\end{proof}  
\end{thm}  

Let's see another proof.
\begin{proof}
\begin{itemize}
\item Fact one
\item Fact two
\item Fact three\qedhere
\end{itemize}
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
Here the proof ends with an \texttt{align*} environment.
\begin{align*}
0&=0+0\\
1&=0+1\qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This definitely solves everything but one thing: the `\qedhere` command does not suppress the default `\qedsymbol` at the end of the proof. Putting `\qedhere` before the end of the proof results in two hollow squares printed, the one called by `\qedhere` and the default one at the end.

Comment: @AndreasT `\qedhere` should be used only in the last line, if it's not a normal paragraph, just like in the examples I showed.

Comment: That's true, but the original `\qedhere` command can be put anywhere and the default hollow square is suppressed. I agree with what you say and in fact that is how I have always used `\qedhere` so far. The philosophy behind my previous comment was just trying to reestablish the original `\qedhere` command with all its features, but I guess some are quite useless.

Thank you very much, the question is fully solved.

Comment: @AndreasT While your request is understandable, one should plunge into the details of `ntheorem` and its QED mark placement in order to build the infrastructure: remember that `\qedhere` in `amsmath` uses a stack to cope with nested proof environments. And that apparently `ntheorem` checks whether the proof actually ends just after the inner environment (display or list) in order to decide if placing `\qed` or `\proofSymbol`. This seems more a feature request for `ntheorem`.

Comment: the qedhere suggested here not only creates the box at the end where i want it, but also adds one to the previous display (\[ \]). what's going on?

Comment: @peter I don't get doubled QED symbols.

Comment: actually the problem discussed here must be old. seems like ntheorem puts the qed where it belongs even without \qedhere. so my problems have disappeared.